# Can Lion OSX Search in App's Contents

Tags: macos, search

How can I configure Lion to search for files in the Contents of an .app?

Answer (score 2):

**Easy Solution**
For a free GUI solution, you could use [EasyFind](http://www.devon-technologies.com/download/index.html). To search inside applications, you just need to check "Package Contents" in the sidebar.

For a quicker search, you can limit the search to just the Applications folder by using the menu under the search field (on the far right).

**Command Line - Find**
In Terminal, you can use the `find` command:

```
find /Applications/foo.app -type f -name "bar"
```

Replace `foo.app` with the name of your app, and replace `"bar"` with the name of the file you want to search for.

If you want to search all apps in /Applications, leave out the `/foo.app` part of the command.

If you want to include folders, remove `-type f`, if you want to search *only* for folders, change `-type f` to `-type d`. You can also use the `*` wildcard in your filename to get partially matching results.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think so, but I'll be happy to hear otherwise. It's quite easy from the command line, though:

```
find /Applications/<YOUR APP>.app -type f | xargs strings | grep <YOUR SEARCH TERM>
```

You can also search through the whole Applications folder with

```
find /Applications -type f | xargs strings | grep <YOUR SEARCH TERM>
```

This will take quite a while, as it actually searches through the files instead of using a cached index, like Spotlight does.

Answer (score 0):

### [Find Any File](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/)

is a third-party utility that can do this. It costs US $4.00 and can be downloaded from the developer or purchased in the Mac App Store. It is a good alternative to using the command-line tools that come with Lion. It can also be run as "root" to access even more files than what Mac OS X usually lets the user see.

[image]